# How to generate AndroidTestCoverageReport when Test Fails?

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso

I am able to generate `AndroidTestCoverageReport` when all my test pass. But when any of the test fails, `AndroidTestCoverageReport` is not generated. Is there any way I can bypass the failed scenario and still generate `AndroidTestCoverageReport`.

Comment: How do you generate the report?

Comment: gradle createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport